# Faltan archivos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vscode, npm, build

tengo un problema que no se si será por una mala configuración o algo mas, y es que a la hora de compilar el código con npm run build, compruebo la carpeta build y en todos los casos se salta por completo la carpeta SRC incluido el App.js. Carpeta Build:

[image: Carpeta Build del proyecto falta toda la carpeta SRC entre otros archivos]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la configuración de tu archivo `webpack`?

Comment: yo hice la aplicación con create react-app, lo unico que tengo son los archivos package.json y package-lock.json.